# DeprecationWarning: grpc.load

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, socket.io

I am building an app which uses client-server communication and server-google cloud platform communications by using socket.io. For the front-end part, I'm using React where I have two components.

But I get the following error in the compiling time:

```
Server is listening on port: 1337
(node:21711) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::1337
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1355:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1480:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/server.js:172:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at loader (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous
```

Comment: I saw this:

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/issues/301

Comment: So I am not sure if the warning is causing me the error or they are different things, I mean one is a display warning and the other is an error not related to that warning

Comment: Its showing the port is already in used,  Change the port  and start the server again .

Comment: That works! But now I'm getting a different error. 

`events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:1000`

Comment: The EACCES error was showing since I have to run node as root in order to bind to those certain ports.

Comment: On which port you are running ,if its 80 run node from root otherwise set port above to 1024

Comment: That works too. It's even better so I do not need to use root.